# Trigger Actualiza valor de columna

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Hola a todos estoy un poco nuevo en esto de administracion de BBDD con SQL y tengo un dudas al generar un triger para actualizar un campo de una tabla.
Les detallo mas a continuacion.

Tengo estas 3 Tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y requiero hacer un Trigger que me actualice el campo [Total Product] cada vez que haya un nueva Orden de un determinado empleado sea insertada.

Me complica el hecho de que el campo que debo actualizar tiene relacion con dos tablas mas.

Ademas de que debo hacer una consulta gorup by para poder optener el total de productos vendidos.

Comment: ¿No sería mejor generar una vista con esos datos? Hacerlo en un trigger podría consumir más recursos de los necesarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te voy a dar una de las posibles soluciones a lo que planteas, pero ya te indico de antemano, que no está bien, porque la normalización dice que la columna `Total Products`, no es ningún atributo de un empleado.

```
Create table dbo.Orders 
(Order_id int, EmployeeId int);
Insert into dbo.Orders (Order_Id, EmployeeId)
values
(1,4),
(2,5),
(3,6),
(4,4),
(5,5);

Create table [Order Details]
(Order_id int, Quantity int)
Insert into [Order Details]
(Order_id, Quantity)
Values
(1,2),
(2,12),
(3,10),
(4,16),
(5,21);

Create table dbo.Employees 
(EmployeeId int, [Total Product] int)
Insert into dbo.Employees 
(EmployeeId,[Total Product])
Values
(4,18),
(5,33),
(6,10);
```

Hasta aquí era el escenario que indicas con capturas.

**Trigger**

```
Create trigger dbo.OrderDetailsInsert
on dbo.[Order Details]
After Insert
As
Begin
    ;with cte as (
        Select SUM(quantity) as cantidad, i.Order_id
        from inserted i
        Group by Order_id
    ), myOrder as 
    (
        Select Orders.EmployeeId, cte.cantidad
        From Orders inner join cte 
            on Orders.Order_id = cte.Order_id
    )
    Update e
        set [Total Product]
        = IsNull(e.[Total Product],0)+myOrder.cantidad
    From dbo.Employees e join myOrder 
    On myOrder.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId;

End;
```

Si observas el código del trigger, quien lo tiene que disparar no es ordenes, porque seguro que primero se inserta la orden y luego sus detalles, por tanto y dado que la columna que establece la cantidad es de `[order details]`, es esta tabla la que tiene que tener ***los*** triggers. Remarco los porque, si borras un detalle o modificas un detalle, o una orden, lo lógico sería que se recalculase el total de productos del/los empleados incluidos en esos borrados o modificaciones.

En la primera parte del trigger calculamos la suma de las cantidades que contenga la sentencia de inserción por orden (no olvidar nunca que una sentencia insert puede insertar varias filas a la vez).

Luego en el segundo conjunto `myOrder`, buscamos a los empleados y relacionamos con el anterior, para tener las cantidades por empleado.

A la salida de la misma, realizamos la update de la tabla employees.

```
Insert into dbo.Employees(EmployeeId, [Total Product])
values
(7,null);

Insert into dbo.Orders (Order_id, EmployeeId)
values
(6,7);

Insert into dbo.[Order Details]
(Order_id, Quantity)
Values
(6,7);
```

El resultado:

```
Select * 
from dbo.Employees;
```

[image: Res1]

Claro que ahora hay que hacer un trigger, para el borrado y otro para la modificación de la tabla de los detalles.

**Vista**

Y la solución más lógica, no sería usar una vista.

```
Drop trigger dbo.OrderDetailsInsert;
Drop table dbo.Employees;
Create table dbo.Employees 
(EmployeeId int)
Insert into dbo.Employees 
(EmployeeId)
Values
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7);
```

En el mismo punto de partida, solo que la tabla `Employees` no tiene `Total Products`.

```
Create view dbo.EmployeesWithProduct
As
    Select 
        SUM(quantity) as [Total Products], e.EmployeeId 
        From dbo.Employees e 
            left join dbo.Orders o
            on e.EmployeeId = O.EmployeeId
            left join dbo.[Order Details] od
            on o.Order_id = od.Order_id
        group by e.EmployeeId;
```

Ahora tenemos una vista que nos devuelve esa información.

```
Select * 
    from dbo.EmployeesWithProduct;
```

[image: Res2]

[Trigger After Insert](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/12/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-insert/)

[Trigger After Update](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/15/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-update/)

[Trigger After Delete](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/18/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-delete/)

[Tablas de expresión común (cte)](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/)